# NGINX - forbidden custom message

Tags: nginx

I'd like to serve different content based on user's IP/network.

example:

If user comes from network: 1.0.0.0/8 or 12.0.0.0/8 users gets alternative content Vs if user comes from any other IP/network, in which case user gets normal content.

how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found this...

[Nginx: Custom Error 403 Page Not Working with IP Deny Configuration](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-nginx-custom-error-403-page-configuration/)